# Gettin this in( Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException ) annotation example

Tags: java, annotations

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@interface MyAnno{
    String str();
    int val();


}
public class Meta {
@MyAnno(str ="Annotation Example",val=100)
public static void myMeth(){
    Meta ob =  new Meta();
    try{
         Class c = ob.getClass();
        Method m = c.getMethod("myMeth");

        MyAnno anno = m.getAnnotation(MyAnno.class );
        System.out.println(anno.str()+" "+anno.val());
    }catch (NoSuchMethodException exc){
        System.out.println("Method not found");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myMeth();
}

}
```

while running this program getting this null pointer exception ,can anyone explain why            and how to catch this exception and finally fix this  code ?

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException    
   at Meta.myMeth(Meta.java:19)
   at Meta.main(Meta.java:25)
```

Comment: add your stacktrace please

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Meta.myMeth(Meta.java:19)
 at Meta.main(Meta.java:25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to retain the annotation at runtime. When you specify `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`, this is not done as the doc says:

> Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler but
>   need not be retained by the VM at run time.

So change it to `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`

Answer (score 1):

The `CLASS` `RetentionPolicy` is not retained by the VM at runtime. You could use

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```